# Unable to adjust brightness on a Sony VAIO F133FXB

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, vaio

I cant control my laptop screen brightness with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> keys and also with Brightness control tool in settings.
I tried to edit xorg.conf file but it didn't work (after restart my ubuntu didn't boot!)
System info: Ubuntu 11.10; VAIO F133FXB with NVIDIA 425M graphic card (updated).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following kernel options to your Grub defaults

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add the options

```
acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux
```

So the line looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Then update grub and reboot

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```